# AJAX stay on form, SQL isnt getting input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, sql-update

So I realize that the problem is only at the sql order to update,
I need it to insert to specific row and specific col, the row is determind by the user id who I get through the session.. I did it before I am just not sure How Can I search the id and to that row the value?

by the way does "mysqli_real_escape_string" make the SQL more safe?

```
include_once 'dhb.inc.php';


$etherwallet = $_POST['name'];
$idbridge1 = $_SESSION['u_id'];

if (empty($etherwallet)) {
    exit();
} else {
    if (strlen($etherwallet) != 42 ) {
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE users WHERE user_id = '$idbridge1' SET eth_wallet = '$etherwallet'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$idbridge1` doesnt seem to be set. You can log, or output the `$_POST` to see what was sent by the AJAX. `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: when learning get used to _allways check for errors_ und use built in error functions such as `echo mysqli_error();` (after the query), which would habe been very usefull in your case!

Comment: also get used to (and only use!) [prepared stements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). The way you query the database is at highly risk for attacks. I know you're learning, but better learn it the right way from the beginning.

Comment: I already got prepared stements, I just tried to be clear as possible.
Anyway I tried to echo, the data does send But when I try to Echo the
$etherwallet is seems to be empty for some reason, so I think thats why the SQL seems empty, They way That I insert Data is not correct? Thanks

Comment: You shouldnt escape with prepared statements. The query should be parameterized.

Comment: I editted the problem Its really only the SQL problem How can I Fix it?